# Debit Card Input Formatting

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling with an annoying problem. I am trying to format user input for a debit card number. Problem is, the entered input should be like this format in an editText

Format: DE XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX

The thing is,edittext should be prefilled with DE and it should be uneditable and gray colored,once your user starts to enter numbers, the format should look like this. and card contains always 22 digits.

I couldn't make such a masking for a week now.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

For prefill option, you can use use textview along with edit text inside a relative layout.
You can place the TextView at starting of edit text and give edittext paddingStart till the textview(DE in your case).

For formatting the remaining, you an use textwatcher's ontextChange method by saving each character in backend and replace each one with X.

Comment: also split the card number in 4 edittexts with their respective text change listeners and after 4 digits are entered make the next one focusable.

Comment: this approach sounds like a workaround because if a user wants to delete the numbers, focuses will be messed up

Comment: As far as my concern, you have only this option to achieve the same if you don't wan't to use any library.